# Sorting update history in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sorting, sql-order-by

Basically, I am keeping a record of update history for my software in a MySQL table. When I output this data, I want the data to be sorted by the software version in descending order i.e. the newest version update information is outputted first.

I am using the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM updates WHERE productId='$productId' ORDER BY version DESC
```

on the following test data:

```
1.0.0
0.9.8
2.4.2
1.7.0
1.7.1
17.2.1
```

The output is:

```
2.4.2
17.2.1
1.7.1
1.7.0
1.0.0
0.9.8
```

Because of the 2 'decimal points' in the data, I can't store it in the table as double, float etc. so is stored as varchar.

I tried putting `ORDER BY version+0 DESC` in the query, which does move the `17.2.1` to the top of the list, but moves the `1.7.0` above the `1.7.1` because the casting breaks when it reaches the second decimal point, so is just outputting the data in the order of the table.

Any suggestions on how to sort the data so that it would come out as:

```
17.2.1
2.4.2
1.7.1
1.7.0
1.0.0
0.9.8
```

Cheers!

Comment: why not break that column into 3 fields? much easier to order the records.

Comment: what about this one: http://injustfiveminutes.wordpress.com/2012/10/17/split-function-in-mysql/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work

```
select * from Table1
order by CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(version, '.', 1) as DECIMAL) DESC, 
CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(version, '.', 2), '.', -1) as DECIMAL DESC,
CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(version, '.', -1) as DECIMAL) DESC;
```

[Check Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9bd9f/15)

Comment: Thanks that works great, +1 for the Fiddle too. Just wondering what are the downsides (mainly execution time) of having 3 casts in there - is it likely to be a huge issue with the processing power in modern systems?

Comment: yes ,first * you can reduce it to two cast by trick. second * do not sort in table , if u are using php then there is a function **natsort** then can do same thing for you, and every language have such type of function.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from Table1
order by CAST(version  AS DECIMAL) DESC;
```

**[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bff40/5)**

Comment: it will not work if one value 17.4.1 is added in your sql fiddle . check that

Comment: This gives the same output as shown in my question with the `version+0` - 1.7.0 is shown before 1.7.1.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT * FROM Table1 ORDER BY inet_aton(version);

Comment: Works like a charm thanks! What does the inet_aton part actually do? Computationally is that better to use than the casts mentioned by melc and developerCK?

Comment: The inet_aton function works exactly as described in the manual ;-). Basically, it converts between integers and internet addresses. Internet addresses happen to be written in base 256 with dots in between, so as long as versions fit within the format '255.255.255.255', you should be fine.

Comment: Haha I thought I would get that response, so did check it out briefly as well ;) Does it not cause problems the fact that it's not in proper IPv4 format, i.e. I have x.x.x instead of x.x.x.x? Also I'm guessing it would cause issues if they weren't all formatted the same, e.g. would 1.1.1 and 1.2 break the sorting, and it would have to be 1.2.0 instead?

Comment: Ok great, could always use php to format it as I like, as long as it's stored in the table correctly. Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT VERSION,
CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(VERSION,'.',1) AS UNSIGNED) v1,
CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(VERSION,'.',2),'.',-1) AS UNSIGNED) v2,
CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(VERSION,'.',-1) AS UNSIGNED) v3
FROM UPDATES
ORDER BY v1 DESC, v2 DESC, v3 DESC
```

Comment: Just a personal preference but the data is given as 3 separate parts meaning more work to do putting it back together again to output, whereas developerCK's solution with the inline `DESC`'s outputs it all as one. Thanks for the answer though :) +1

Answer (score 0):

Not ORDER BY version but:

extract number until full stop and order by first number, second and third

like this:

```
ORDER BY firstVersionNumber, secondVersionNumber, thirdVersionNumber.
```

To extract number use string function